# My global variable is not changing after the first loop in Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino

I am trying to do a toggle for turning on a LED with a push-up button, I've tried many things, and finally came up with this:

```
int boton_en=0;
int parar=0;


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
pinMode(4, OUTPUT);       

pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP); 
pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP); 
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 boton_en  = digitalRead(8);

if (boton_en == LOW){
  parar = 1 - parar;
  }
if (parar == 1){
  digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(4,LOW);
  }
  }
```

The LED turns on after the first push of the button, but any consecutive pushes dont turn it off. Any help / commentary helps. :)

Comment: You need to look at the State Change example and alter your variable only once per press.  As written you press the button and the light gets turned on.  Then a few microseconds later the loop function repeats and the button is still pressed so it turns it back off.  This happens way too fast for your eye to see it.  As long as you are holding the button the light is going on and off over and over several times per millisecond.  When you let go of the button it happens to settle on off.  It's really a crap-shoot whether the light will end up on or off.

Comment: So unless you are superman and can actually press and release a button in under a microsecond, this code won't work.

Comment: I see, is there any way I could fix this issue? I've heard about setting the debounce, but dont actually get it, could you recommend me a page where I can find information? (And thanks btw :P)

Comment: It's not switch bounce.  I told you where to find the simple example.  Go look at the State Change Example.  It comes with the IDE.  Once you get that, then you can deal with switch bounce.  But right now you're not up to that problem yet.  You are still reacting to the button BEING pressed when you want to react to it BECOMING pressed.  That is to say, you only want to alter your variable when the button is pressed now but wasn't pressed on the last loop.   The example I pointed you to couldn't be simpler.  Have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [switch tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/switch) from arduino website.

[image: A push-button on pin 2 and an LED on pin 13]

```c
/* switch
 * 
 * Each time the input pin goes from LOW to HIGH (e.g. because of a push-button
 * press), the output pin is toggled from LOW to HIGH or HIGH to LOW.  There's
 * a minimum delay between toggles to debounce the circuit (i.e. to ignore
 * noise).  
 *
 * David A. Mellis
 * 21 November 2006
 */

int inPin = 2;         // the number of the input pin
int outPin = 13;       // the number of the output pin

int state = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time = 0;         // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounce = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers

void setup()
{
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(outPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  reading = digitalRead(inPin);

  // if the input just went from LOW and HIGH and we've waited long enough
  // to ignore any noise on the circuit, toggle the output pin and remember
  // the time
  if (reading == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
    if (state == HIGH)
      state = LOW;
    else
      state = HIGH;

    time = millis();    
  }

  digitalWrite(outPin, state);

  previous = reading;
}
```